# Редирект nginx настройка

Tags: linux, nginx

Требуется сделать редирект с `http://site.com/code="abs"` на `https://site_new.com/code="abs"`
Пытался вот так:

```
proxy_redirect http://login-tech.mos.ru https://$servername/sps/console/login/callback$request_uri?
```

не работает